# "Prodotti da tenere presente" oppure "prodotti da tenere presenti"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, grammatical-number, agreement

Cercando su Internet, su siti commerciali o di pubblicità, ho trovato molte volte l'espressione "prodotti da tenere presente", ma anche alcune (poche) volte "prodotti da tenere presenti". Quale tra queste due è la forma corretta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma corretta è senz'altro “tener(e) presenti”: il dizionario Devoto-Oli (di cui ho sotto mano l'edizione 1990), alla voce *presente*, esemplifica tra l'altro «bisogna tener presenti alcune difficoltà». In frasi così l'accordo è con il complemento oggetto, non diversamente da quel che succede per «tenere aperta la giacca», «tener desta l'attenzione» etc.

Il motivo per cui si trova anche il singolare, probabilmente, è che nella mente di alcuni “tenere presente” è trattato come una forma unica, invariante.

Comment: Ammetto che la forma plurale è, diciamo, più corretta di quella singolare, tuttavia non sono d'accordo sul "senz'altro". La forma "tenere present* gli oggetti" è del tutto assimilabile ad altre del tipo "tenere a mente", "tenere in memoria" e via dicendo. Direi che formalmente la forma plurale è quella corretta, ma non è biasimabile quella al singolare: fa parte del linguaggio comune ed è riscontrabile in numerosi testi didattici.

Comment: Infatti su Google Books si trovano moltissimi esempi con l'espressione "da tenere presenti".

Comment: @MarioVernari: Grazie per il commento. Direi che la vera differenza è che “presente” è un aggettivo, che quindi va concordato, mentre negli esempi che fai “tenere” si costruisce con espressioni invariabili (“a mente” etc.).

Answer (score 1):

A mio avviso la seconda formula è sbagliata. Il termine "tenere presente" dovrebbe fare riferimento "all'attenzione" che il lettore dà al/ai prodotto/i. In altre parole, la frase completa suonerebbe "prodotti (sui quali l'attenzione è) da tenere presente".

Non direi proprio che si faccia riferimento ai prodotti stessi.

Considera che non è affatto raro trovare inesattezze, errori e simili su giornali, TV e pubblicità varie.

EDIT: Aspetta: potrebbe però esserci un secondo significato. Se l'intenzione di chi scrive è quella di "prodotti da tenere presenti (sullo scaffale)", allora è accettabile. Direi che dipende dal contesto.

Comment: Non sono d'accordo e ritengo che “presente” debba concordarsi proprio con i prodotti o quel che sia (che vanno, parafrasando, mantenuti vivi alla mente dell'interlocutore), ma non trovo una fonte che confermi o smentisca questa tesi. Puoi spiegare meglio come “presente” si riferisca all'attenzione? C'è qualcosa di sottinteso? Se cioè la costruzione originaria fosse stata “dovete tenere l'attenzione presente”, poi dovrebbe seguire qualcosa come “per/su/verso i prodotti”, no?

Comment: Sottolineo che la lingua italiana NON è il mio forte. Detto questo, sono d'accordo con l'alternativa "tenere a mente": forse è pure meglio, in effetti. Sta di fatto che non riesco a vedere il plurale nella forma di questo contesto. L'unico caso che vedrei accettabile il plurale è quello che ho aggiunto successivamente. Concordo infine sulla difficoltà di trovare fonti (cercherò di chiedere a chi è più colto di me).

Answer (score -1):

Credo che la tua domanda possa  trarre in inganno anche gli italiani per via dell'uso idiomatico del verbo "tenere".

Tu sei spagnola e in spagnolo "tenere" equivale all'italiano "avere", ma in realtà il corretto significato è quello di "mantenere". Accade che nel sud dell'Italia, per via della dominazione spagnola, si continui a usare nel linguaggio colloquiale, dialettale  o comunque da parte di chi è poco istruito "tenere" nel senso di "avere", ad esempio: "tengo fame", che è sbagliato in italiano. Quando usi  il verbo "tenere" pensa sempre a se lo puoi sostituirlo con "avere". Casi in cui è sicuramente corretto usare "tenere" sono: "tenere il punto",  "tenere un comportamento", "tenere una pistola in pugno". Puoi   sostituirlo con "mantenere", salvo nell'ultimo caso, perché ripeteresti due volte il riferimento alla mano.

Per significare "ricordare" meglio "aver presente" o "tener presente"?

In generale è preferibile "avere", ad esempio: "Ho presente quello che mi hai detto.", ma, quando si passa alla seconda persona (imperativo), puoi dire sia "abbi presente che ..." sia "tieni presente che ...".
La seconda è una forma idiomatica, che funge da rafforzativo: "Ti esorto a mantenere nella tua mente questo concetto.".

Dunque "tener presente" è a tutti gli effetti equivalente al verbo "ricordare", come nell'inglese "to keep in mind". Questa equazione è oramai automatica nei parlanti: "tenere presente = ricordare".

Dunque, con riferimento alla tua frase:
"Prodotti il cui ricordo va tenuto presente nella propria mente = Prodotti da tenere presente = Prodotti da ricordare"

Il singolare sembra preferibile poiché tu, non vuoi *tenere* nella tua mente i singoli prodotti, ma il *ricordo* dei prodotti. 
Inoltre, poiché l'associazione mentale  "tenere presente = ricordare" è molto forte, "tenere presenti", genera un immediato fastidio all'orecchio di chi ti ascolta o legge.

Attenzione!  Tutto questo non vale (come ti è già stato fatto notare) se, invece di voler conservare il ricordo dei prodotti, vogliamo conservare i prodotti stessi negli scaffali di casa.

Di norma le pubblicità vogliono indurre i consumatori a ricordare i prodotti di cui trattano, ma è di certo corretto dire: "Tenete sempre presenti nelle vostre cucine le nostre bottiglie di acqua minerale e vivrete più a lungo."